# Candle decimal places

Tags: c#, bitfinex

What is the query param to specify the decimal precision in Bitfinex API v2?

Seemly the default precision is ####.0, but i want a "precision more precise" than only one decimal place

[image: BTCUSD candle]

Answer (score 1):

The Bitfinex:BTC/USD pair seems to be traded with one decimal figure precision.

There is no way to get more accurate data, as this is the most accurate data.

In my opinion one decimal figure is enough. Since BTCs price is so high, the first decimal figure is actualy the 5th significant figure. Most forex exchanges only go to 6 significant figures.